# Supabase social auth: Unable to match the desired swap behavior

Tags: android, flutter, dart, supabase

When I try to use google oauth with supabase auth ui on Flutter, the following error message has shown.

E/OpenGLRenderer( 8967): Unable to match the desired swap behavior.

Judging from supabase auth console, I can login to my google account successfully but cannot  execute the function in the onSuccess property.

My device is Pixel 5a.

Supabase auth ui
https://pub.dev/packages/supabase_auth_ui

```dart
class SociallAuth extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SupaSocialsAuth(
      colored: true,
      socialProviders: const [
        SocialProviders.google,
      ],
      redirectUrl: "io.supabase.flutterquickstart://login-callback",
      onSuccess: (Session response) {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Home()),
        );
      },
      onError: (error) {
        debugPrint(error.toString());
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I want to execute

```
Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Home()),);
```

Comment: `Unable to match the desired swap behavior.` should be just a warning. Check if you have any other actual error messages.